# Images are not working with React Native + TypeScript + Expo

Tags: typescript, react-native, expo

I am building a CRNA with Typescript and I cannot seem to get images to resolve properly. I've followed the docs here to no avail: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images

This is the error I get when building the to both IOS and Android simulators:

```
Unable to resolve ./img.png" from ".//build/components/PlateCounter.js`: The module `./img.png` could not be found"
Failed building JavaScript bundle
```

The images do not appear in the /build folder with my .js files after compiling, so I imagine that is causing the Expo build failure, but I do not know how to get the images to compile into `/build`
[Build folder screenshot/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fvOv3.png)

Here's the component I'm trying to render the image in:

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Image } from 'react-native';

export default class PlateCounter extends React.Component<any, any> {

  public render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Image source={require('./img.png')} />
      </View>
   );
  }
}
```

And here's the file structure for that folder: [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vz2Hc.png)

As you can see in the image I've tried adding @2x and @3x variants, this did not change anything.

My package.json:

```
{
  "name": "TestRN",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^16.4.14",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.0.7",
    "@types/react-native": "^0.56.21",
    "@types/react-navigation": "^2.0.21",
    "concurrently": "^4.0.1",
    "react-native-scripts": "1.14.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.3.1",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.2",
    "tslint": "^5.11.0",
    "typescript": "^3.0.3"
  },
  "main": "./node_modules/react-native-scripts/build/bin/crna-entry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "tslint src/**/*.ts",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "clean": "rimraf build",
    "build": "yarn run clean && yarn run tsc --",
    "watch": "yarn run build -- -w",
    "watchAndRunAndroid": "concurrently \"yarn run watch\" \"yarn run android\"",
    "buildRunAndroid": "yarn run build && yarn run watchAndRunAndroid ",
    "watchAndRunIOS": "concurrently \"yarn run watch\" \"yarn run ios\"",
    "buildRunIOS": "yarn run build && yarn run watchAndRunIOS ",
    "watchAndStart": "concurrently \"yarn run watch\" \"yarn run start\"",
    "buildAndStart": "yarn run build && yarn run watchAndStart ",
    "start": "react-native-scripts start",
    "eject": "react-native-scripts eject",
    "android": "react-native-scripts android",
    "ios": "react-native-scripts ios",
    "debug": "REACT_DEBUGGER=\"unset ELECTRON_RUN_AS_NODE\" && open -g 'rndebugger://set-debugger-loc?port=19001'"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^6.3.1",
    "expo": "^27.0.1",
    "native-base": "^2.8.0",
    "react": "16.3.1",
    "react-native": "~0.55.2",
    "react-navigation": "^2.14.2",
    "unstated": "^2.1.1",
    "watchman": "^1.0.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use following code and please make sure your file is having proper permissions.

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Image } from 'react-native';

export default class PlateCounter extends React.Component<any, any> {

  public render() {
    let imgSource = require('./img.png');
    return (
      <View>
        <Image source={imgSource} />
      </View>
   );
  }
}
```